# Function in python to remove users who haven't purchased a specific brand/item from a pool of transactions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I'm trying to segment customers based on purchases for specific brands, one segment is for users who never bought Volvic and the other is users who have bought Volvic water, the dataset contains records of 12 months by date and transaction level (items details)

| Date | User_ID | Trxn_ID | Brand | Item_description | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/23 | 1234567 | 100001 | AQUA | AQUA WATER 10x400ML | 14 |
| 1/1/23 | 1234567 | 100001 | VOLVIC | VOLVIC WATER 330ML | 1.7 |
| 1/1/23 | 1234567 | 100001 | OSKA | OSKA WATER 330 ML | 0.5 |
| 1/19/23 | 1234567 | 100002 | AQUA | AQUA WATER 24x330ML | 15 |
| 1/19/23 | 1234567 | 100002 | OSKA | OSKA WATER 10x330ML | 5 |
| 1/19/23 | 6543210 | 100003 | VOLVIC | VOLVIC WATER 24x330ML | 30 |
| 1/19/23 | 6543210 | 100003 | AQUA | AQUA WATER 24x330ML | 15 |
| 1/1/23 | 4567890 | 100004 | AQUA | AQUA WATER 24x330ML | 15 |
| 1/1/23 | 4567890 | 100004 | OSKA | OSKA WATER 10x330 ML | 5 |

Based on the segments' criteria mentioned above for each, I need to check if Volvic has been purchased in any of the User's trxn_ID and if this condition is true then user has to be removed from the list, and vice versa for the other one.

The result should be something like below:

Never bought Volvic:

| User_ID |
| --- |
| 4567890 |

Ever bought Volvic

```
| User_ID |
|---------|
| 1234567 |
| 6543210 |
```

Appreciate any help here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['check'] = df['Item_description'].str.contains('Volvic')
new_df = df[['User_ID', 'check']].groupby('User_ID').any()
```

This should do it.

1. step 1 creates a boolean column which is True whenever a user bought Vovic
2. step 2 groups by the user and return True or False if that user did or didn't buy Vovic